# Accounting for spatial autocorrelation in model - A simulation

Tags: lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, spatial, generalized-least-squares

My question, **in short**, is:

I was trying to demonstrate that accounting for spatial autocorrelation reduces the overestimation of significance of a non-autocorrelated fixed effect. The result, however, does correspond to my expectation and I am not sure why.

**The long version:**

I am simulating a spatial phenomenon, consisting of:

1. A "fixed" effect, which is not spatially autocorrelated, where the value of each cell is just a random sample from a normal distribution.
2. A "random" spatially autocorrelated effect, which is a simulation of a random autocorrelated process.
3. A response, which is the sum of the two.

Here is an image of the three surfaces, from one of the simulations - 
[image]

Then, I am fitting two types of models (in R).

The first model is a simple linear regression (`lm`), which only includes the "fixed" effect:

```r
lm(
  formula = response ~ fixed, 
  data = dat
)
```

The second model is a Mixed Model (`gls`) which accounts for spatial autocorrelation:

```r
gls(
  model = response ~ fixed, 
  data = dat, 
  correlation = corExp(form = ~ x + y, nugget = TRUE), 
  method = "REML"
)
```

The simulations are repeated, with two things varying between runs:

1. The sample (`dat`) is an increasing number of points randomly spread over the surface, ranging from `20` to `300` points

For example, here is an illustration of `300` randomly placed sampling points - 
[image]

2. The "fixed" surface is multiplied by a fixed coefficient ranging from `0` to `0.25` to create an increasing effect size

My expectation was that:

1. using a linear regression, the "fixed" effect is going to be significant given sufficiently large sample size, even if the true effect is zero, while
2. using a Mixed Model significance will depend on the "true" *effect size*, not sample size

The result, shown below, does not correspond to my expectation -

[image]

The result shows different simulated surfaces (seven panel rows) and different "fixed" surface effect sizes (five panel columns), whereas in each panel the X-axis gives the sample size while the Y-axis gives the detected "fixed" effect. Only significant effects are plotted. The horizontal lines in each panel are the true effect sizes.

The result is quite the opposite of what I expected: linear regression seems to *underestimate* the effect, so when effect size is small the effect is undetected with linear regression but is detected using a Mixed Model. Moreover, when true effect size is zero (the panels in the first column), the Mixed Model erroneously detects it more often than linear regression.

A reproducible R script can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3r0p0s1uoi4t9e/code_05.R?dl=1

I am not a statistician, and my knowledge on this comes from general guidance such as the "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R" book by Zuur et al. Will be happy to hear any guidance: for example, whether the my expectation was wrong, or perhaps the simulation was inappropriate. Also, will be happy to hear if there are any useful resources on this matter, which do not require a broad mathematical/statistical education to follow.

Thanks for any help,

Michael